# Building SVO package on Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

Im building svo package following this guide https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/wiki/Run-SVO-without-ROS on raspberry pi.

Everything except last package builded succesfully. While building last package I faced next error:

```
/home/pi/workspace/rpg_svo/svo/src/map.cpp: In member function ‘svo::FramePtr svo::Map::getClosestKeyframe(const FramePtr&) const’:
/home/pi/workspace/rpg_svo/svo/src/map.cpp:135:12: error: could not convert ‘nullptr’ from ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘svo::FramePtr {aka boost::shared_ptr<svo::Frame>}’
CMakeFiles/svo.dir/build.make:146: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/svo.dir/src/map.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/svo.dir/src/map.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/svo.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/svo.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I builded everything except SVO package with:

```
export ARM_ARCHITECTURE=True
```

And changed compilers flags: I deleted `-march=native`. Also I tried to add these flags:

```
-march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp
```

But it changed nothing.

Full building log:

```
Scanning dependencies of target svo
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/svo.dir/src/frame_handler_mono.cpp.o
/tmp/ccqAImPE.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccqAImPE.s:1875: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/ccqAImPE.s:1885: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/ccqAImPE.s:1902: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/ccqAImPE.s:2077: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/ccqAImPE.s:2087: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/ccqAImPE.s:2104: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/ccqAImPE.s:2161: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/ccqAImPE.s:2171: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/ccqAImPE.s:2188: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
[  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/svo.dir/src/frame_handler_base.cpp.o
/tmp/cclVVat6.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:3429: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:3439: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:3456: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:3513: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:3523: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:3540: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:4324: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:4333: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:4350: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:4684: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:4693: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/cclVVat6.s:4710: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/svo.dir/src/frame.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/svo.dir/src/point.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/svo.dir/src/map.cpp.o
/home/pi/workspace/rpg_svo/svo/src/map.cpp: In member function ‘svo::FramePtr svo::Map::getClosestKeyframe(const FramePtr&) const’:
/home/pi/workspace/rpg_svo/svo/src/map.cpp:135:12: error: could not convert ‘nullptr’ from ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘svo::FramePtr {aka boost::shared_ptr<svo::Frame>}’
CMakeFiles/svo.dir/build.make:146: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/svo.dir/src/map.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/svo.dir/src/map.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/svo.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/svo.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error: could not convert ‘nullptr’ from ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘svo::FramePtr {aka boost::shared_ptr}

Hi! I have met the same problem as you. I solved this problem by defining a new variable whose type is FramePtr. ie. adding "FramePtr m;"before "return nullptr;"in map.cpp;and then changing "return nullptr"--->"return m;"

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I thought about this trick. But it's strange to me. Because before installing it on Raspbery, I installed it on my normal pc with ubuntu without this error.